# set MCA user id in MQ 7 on a channel

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

Im trying to set MCA user id in MQ explorer 7 on a channel .
where do I get the value of the MCA  ??

Answer (score 1):

The value you put in that field is the ID that will be used by the application connecting via the channel.  That is a complex security issue which needs to be determined by your company.  MQ channels need to be configured so they are secure and do not allow unwanted access.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the channel, you should see the option to add MCA.  Otherwise, if you are trying to add it afterwards, if you right click on the channel names you should be able to select the channel properties and update the MCA field.